# Calling a JS scipt to run a php file and then post html to the relative row

Tags: php, jquery

Follow this if you can...

Basically i have an order form (which begins with one row).

```
<form id="orderform" name"orderForm" action="/secure/delivery-details.html" method="post">
<a  id="add">+</a>
 <table id="ordertable" width="533" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%">Product Code (e.g 66203)</td>
      <td width="33%">Mtrs Required (e.g 10)</td>
      <td width="33%">Preview Image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td class="prodcode"><input type="text" name="prodcode[]" id="prodcode" /></td>
      <td class="meterage"><input type="text" name="meterage[]" id="meterage" /></td>
      <td class="imgsample"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Notice the link with an ID of "add". When checked this adds a new row to the table with the same ID.  Using the code below.

```
    var counter = 0;
    //Order Form
    $("#add").click(function() {
        counter++;
        var cln = $('#ordertable tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
//        cln.find("[id^='prodcode']").each(function(i, val) {
//          val.id = val.id.match(/^([^0-9]+)[0-9]*$/)[1] + "" + counter;
//      });
        cln.insertAfter('#ordertable tbody>tr:last');
        $('#ordertable tbody>tr:last input').val('');
        $('td.imgsample:last a').remove();
        return false;
    });

    //Check for image preview
    $("#prodcode").blur(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this
            .closest('tr') // find the parent tr
            .find('td.imgsample') // find the imgsample in the row
            .html( $(this).attr('id')) // update the contents
            //.animate({'opacity':1},200);

        var imgsample = $this.closest('tr').find('td.imgsample')

        $.post('/public/themes/lbd/js/searchimage.php', //this page reads the image code and gives you the image location
                 { action: 'searchimage', imgreference: $(this).val() },
                function(data) {imgsample.html(data);}
                );
    });
```

My PHP in searchimage...

**When i currently enter a product code if it is invalid it only puts the productID in td.imsample and i want it to say INVALID CODE**

```
//Find image based on Product Code
function findimage($imageToFind) { 

  require '../../../../config.php';
  $dbh = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM isproducts WHERE prodCode = ".strtoupper($imageToFind).""; 
  $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
  $obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $count = $stmt->rowCount();
  if($count > 0) {
      $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM imageindex WHERE filename LIKE '".strtoupper($imageToFind)."-%'"; 
      $stmt2 = $dbh->query($sql2);
      $obj2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      echo ($stmt2->rowCount() == 1 ? '<a href="'.URL_PUBLIC.$obj2->path.'/'.$obj2->filename.'" class="customGal imgfound"><span>'.$obj2->path.'/'.$obj2->filename.'</span></a>&nbsp;<a href="#" class="del">-</a>' : 'No Image Available');    
  } else { 
    echo 'Invalid Code';
  }

}

//Call Function
findimage($_POST['imgreference']);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, can have code errors since I could not test at all:

[jQuery Template](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)

HTML:

```
<script id="template-item" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <tr class="item" id="${id}">
    <td class="prodcode"><input type="text" name="prodcode[]" class="prodcode-input" data="${id}" val="" /></td>
    <td class="meterage"><input type="text" name="meterage[]" class="meterage-input" val="" /></td>
  </tr>
</script>

<form id="orderform" name"orderForm" action="/secure/delivery-details.html" method="post">
 <a href="#" id="add">+</a>
 <table id="ordertable" width="533" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="33%">Product Code (e.g 66203)</th>
        <th width="33%">Mtrs Required (e.g 10)</th>
        <th width="33%">Preview Image</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
       <td class="imgsample"></td>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

    var counter = 0;

    //Check for image preview
    var blur_event = function(ev) {

        var 
          self = $(this),
          imgsample = $("#ordertable tfoot .imgsample");

        $(imgsample).html( $(this).class() ); // update the contents


        $.post('/public/themes/lbd/js/searchimage.php', //this page reads the image code and gives you the image location
            { action: 'searchimage', imgreference: $(self).val() },
            function(data) {
               $(imgsample).html(data);
            }
        );

        return false;

    };

    //Order Form
    $("#add").bind("click", function(ev) {

        counter++;

        var cln = $('#template-item').tmpl({id:"item-"+counter);

//      cln.find("[id^='prodcode']").each(function(i, val) {
//          val.id = val.id.match(/^([^0-9]+)[0-9]*$/)[1] + "" + counter;
//      });

        $(cln).find(".prodcode-input").bind("blur", blur_event);

        $(cln).appendTo('#ordertable tbody');

        return false;

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely due to the duplicated ID.  That makes your HTML document invalid.  See my explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256288/jquery-clone-firefox-bug-cant-submit-a-cloned-form/4256624#4256624).

Comment: Yes it does concern me, but i don't know a way around not using duplicate id's with my JS

Comment: You'll need to find a way around it.  How can JavaScript reliably interact with the DOM when the spec says (paraphrased) "There will be only one element with this ID" and there are actually multiple elements with that ID?  Try using a class instead.  You *will* keep having problems (new ones) until your ID's are no longer duplicate.

Comment: Cheers for your input.  Ill give it a whirl and see how i get on.